# speech to text and text to speech

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                 k = 0;
                    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                        if(result.get(i).contains("X")) {
                            k+=1;

                        }
                        }
                    tv.setText(result.toString()+","+k);
                    if(tv.getText()!=null){
                        if(k>0)
                            tts.speak("bought 2 bananas",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

I tried to do something, and the speech to text works fine. I get all of the possibilities from google now but when I want it to say and do something accordingly (create a command actually) 
It doesn't work.

k means an index to how much times the word "X" (it's in another language and that's why I put X and not the word.) exists in the result ArrayList.
and if k larger than 0, I want the action to happen.

hopes its understandable.

Comment: Why are you checking for null through getText()  and not directly from the String? and it will always return true as there is a comma between the text.

Comment: have you initialized the tts?

Comment: Maybe your language would not be supported.

Comment: @ShashankMishra I did Initialized the tts. 
the language supports the speech to text, so when I want it to talk, I do it in ENGLISH.

Comment: try debugging then.